# Parsing string with multiple delimiters

Tags: c, file, parsing

How could I parse a text file like so:
DISCLAIMER: I CAN NOT ASSUME I KNOW THE CONTENT OF THE TEXT FILE THIS IS JUST A EXAMPLE TEXT FILE

```
10X16 de4 dw9 ds11 g10,7 M3,4 h6,5 p2,2 M8,5 G2,10
12X20 de7 dw10 dn13 g9,10 M7,8 h6,5 p2,2 M8,5 G2,10
```

What this text file is saying is there is a room with the dimensions of `10X16`, a door on the east wall `de4` in the fourth position, `g10,7` means there is a small gold at position `10Y` and `7X`...I do not want to store any letters, the letters are there just to inform me of what the numbers being read are for. I want to store the numbers into `int` variables according to what it is is: gold, monster, potion, etc.

Where I need to store `10` as a `Y` value and `16` as an `X` value, and the other elements after the dimensions are stored in different variables.

Heres my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    //open file and read
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    char line[150];
    char *dim;
    int X = 0;

    while (fgets(line, 150, file) != NULL) {
        dim = strtok(line, "X");
        X = atoi(dim);
        printf("%d\n", X);

        //parse other elements here?
        ...
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

So for example I want `10` in variable `char *roomY` and `16` in `char *roomX`, and `4` to be stored in variable `char *eastDoor`, which will all be converted to `int` values later on.

ALSO elements like `g10,7` I want `10` to be stored as a `Y` value and `7` as a `X` value for that element.

I should also add that the letters should be used to determine what the value is.
Maybe a `if (string[i] = "d")` path for example to be used.

What I have tried is using `strtok(roomY, "X")` to get `X`, and then `int Y = atoi(roomY)` to convert the `char` to an `int` value. That works for just the `10`, but the rest of the file im having trouble parsing correctly. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Have a look at [`sscanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf).

Comment: sscanf doesn't help me parse a 7 and a 10 from an element like g7,10, either that or Im not sure what you have in mind by suggesting it.

Comment: Why not? `sscanf("g7,10", "g%d,%d", &a, &b)` will give you a=7 and b=10.

Comment: sorry i should have specified that i can not assume the contents of the text file

Comment: I am sure the data can change.   is the format consistant?   If the format changes then odds are no amount of code will solve the problem.

Comment: the only thing that is consistent is the dimensions being first ie "10X16" but with different numbers, the elements after will be of a certain list of characters that mean different elements. ie de4 means a door on the east wall on the 4th space/block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to parse the file is to use `strtok` with  `" "` to get the basic tokens and then to evaluate each token based on its identifier with `sscanf`.

```
char* tok = strtok( line, " " );
/* handle first token */
int x, y;
sscanf( tok, "%dX%d", &x, &y );

while( tok = strtok( 0, " " ) )
{
   /* handle token depending on text */
   switch( *tok )
   {
       case 'M' : 
       {
           int mx, my;
           sscanf( tok, "M%d,%d", &mx, &my );
           break;
       }
       // ...
   }
}
```

Please not that this is just a sketch of the solution. You should move the `switch` into some `eval_token` function and each of the cases as well.

Answer (score 0):

My general recommendation for string parsing with C:

Don't try to to everything in one big function, using nested loops, pointers, flags for different parsing modes and so on. This will lead to off-by-one errors, access violations and incomprehensible code.

Instead try to divide the problem into simpler tasks (functions) like splitting a string, replacing specific characters or creating a substring. Then combine these functions to get the desired result.

Or maybe try to find an existing library for string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can use strtok.  The secret is that the delimiter string can contain more than one delimiter.

```
dim = strtok(line, "X ,");
```

Normally I tell people to run screaming from strtok as it has what seems to me to be odd behavior.  In your case I think it may be reasonable.

This one would work ok with 'X', spaces and commas as delimiters.  I would expect 17 values to be scanned.

```
12X20 de7 dw10 dn13 g9,10 M7,8 h6,5 p2,2 M8,5 G2,10
```

This one is different.  Note the triple comma.  Strtok assumes there is no value there. so I would expect 15 values to be scanned.  That may or may not be what you need.  If you were trying to parse a csv file, strtok would be the wrong way to go.

```
12X20 de7 dw10 dn13 g9,10 M7,8 h6,5 p2,,,5 G2,10
```

Comment: ok thats helpful, but the issue is i dont want to store the letters, i want my program to read the letters so that it knows what variable to store the number accompanied by it

Comment: Strtok just iterates though the strings in your input set.  What you do with each string is up to you.   The essential part of your problem is pulling all the pieces out.  The small detail about multiple delimiters should help move you forward.

Comment: how would i store them in individual variables? ie g9,10 would be int goldY = 9 and int goldX = 10

Comment: That is really beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: I understand that, but that was my original problem i was alluding to, your strtok answer was very helpful though, but if you could help me with that aspect of my question that would be extremely helpful as that is the trickiest part for me